# Self hosted wcf service, wsdl references to localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a web application that hosts a service. 
I start the service with:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("http://localhost:{0}/", 12345));
_externalServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyExternalService), uri);
```

When I run this and want to access the wsdl, it contains only links to localhost. But when I access the wsdl out of my machine the link is always over localhost. How can I configure it that it will always point to the right server?

Ps: I am using Visual Studio 2008 with .Net 3.5

Comment: you're hosting your service in localhost , how do you expect the wsdl to contain the address of the external server

Comment: I know this, but how to do it dynamicaly?

Comment: What do ypu mean by dynamically?? you mean using reflection to dynamically load services or what exactly?

Comment: I mean, if someone outside the server wants to acces the wsdl, how do I configure the ServiceHost, that it points in the wsdl to the right link and not to localhost. For example: I call http://mywebservice:12345/ and get the wsdl, but in the wsdl there is a link to http://localhost:12345/?wsdl=wsdl0 . The localhost should always be replaced with the original address, in this case 'mywebservice'. Even if I write the code like this: Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("http://mywebservice:{0}/", 12345)); it references always to localhost in the wsdl.

Comment: I don't think what you're saying is even possible!!! it has nothing to do with WCF , first of all when you deploy your service to your server you won't have localhost, you will have the address of your server and if client are accessing using myserver.com or myser121212.com , it s a dns issue since it will resolve to your server

Comment: Ok, everything you said makes sense, but is there any workaround that I can deploy a wsdl with it's information for everybody that accesses my webservice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78209/discussion-between-franki1986-and-coder1409).

Comment: you can just modify the wsdl manually , give the wsdl to each client with the server adress you want

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config, there should be a block that looks something like this. Change the address attribute.

```
<service name="YOUR.SERVICE.TYPE"
                behaviorConfiguration="YOUR.SERVICE.BEHAVIOR">
         <endpoint name="basicHttpBinding"
                   address="http://your.domain.com/your/service/type"
                   binding="basicHttpBinding"
                   contract="YOUR.SERVICE.CONTRACT"/>
         <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding"
                   contract="IMetadataExchange"
                   binding="mexHttpBinding"
                   address="mex" />
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the acces to the webserver is always different, for example one customer accesses the server with www.myserver.de, the other wants it as www.my12345server.de. So there is always another address. I think it has to be dynamic, based on the address I wrote in the browser. Like if I type 'http://myServer:12345/' the file should show a link like 'http://myserver:12345/?wsdl'.